# Boost Asio - Client to Server Strange output

Tags: asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I am having trouble with Boost asio's packet, let me explain this.

```
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include "../configuration/constants.h" // port = 2013 ; maxLength = 512

class client : public std::enable_shared_from_this<client>
{
public:
    client(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket) : m_socket(std::move(socket)){}

    void start()
    {
        read();
    }

private:
    void read()
    {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        m_socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_data, sizeof(m_data)), [this, self](boost::system::error_code error, std::size_t length)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                std::cout << m_data;
                send(length);
            }
        });
    }

    void send(std::size_t length)
    {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        boost::asio::async_write(m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(m_data, length), [this, self](boost::system::error_code error, std::size_t)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                start();
            }
        });
    }

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_socket;
    char m_data[maxLength];
};

class server
{
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_service& ios, unsigned short port) : m_acceptor(ios, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)), m_socket(ios)
    {
        acceptConnection();
    }

private:
    void acceptConnection()
    {
        m_acceptor.async_accept(m_socket, [this](boost::system::error_code error)
        {
            if (!error)
                std::make_shared<client>(std::move(m_socket))->start();
            acceptConnection();
        });
    }
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_socket;
};

void connexionTCP()
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "TCP open" << std::endl;
        boost::asio::io_service iosConnector;
        server server(iosConnector, port); // port = 2013
        iosConnecteur.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception : " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

If I try to run it, TCP open is the output. If a client send "Hi", the output (in the console) will be :

> HiÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ²²²²½½½½½½½½

The last code is complete. Any idea ? By the way, when I use puTTY as client, when I send "Hi", I receive "Hi". This is only in the console that that write me this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did it.
When I read something, the data length was in the variable size_t length.
So, from it, I did :

```
if (!error) // If there is no error
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (length); i++) // If i < length
        {
            std::cout << m_data[i]; // Print every char since i < length
            if (i == length) // Just to make the output more presentable
                std::cout << "\n"; // Enter
        }
    start(); // Back to the begining.
}
```

Input : "Hi"
Ouput : "Hi" \n

Thanks for your help, Drax and sehe. See you.

The problem I have, at the moment is that I can't stock m_data in a std::string because this is in a for. I tried with vector, but no way. I want to get it because it seemes pretty easier to work with string than with char.
So what I want to do is : Get the for's output m_data in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `'\0'` at the end of your character array before printing it :)

```
if (!error)
{
  m_data[length] = '\0';
  std::cout << m_data;
  send(length);
}
```

Comment: better: just write the data that you have `std::cout.write(m_data, length)` otherwise you just clobbered the last character if `length==maxlength`

Comment: @Drax Your code compile, but this remove only the "²²²²½½½½½½½½". The "ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ" are present. To sehe : Your code compile too, but just write the message 2 times. Thank your for your help, but what I want to do is to remove those 2. I though about splitter, but I don't think in a network handler it is a great idea.

Comment: @NorthernLight No. My code doesn't write the message two times. If it appears to do so, you are doing that in some other line of code :) (Are you, by any chance, mixing up output of "sender" and "receiver" on a single console?)

Comment: I am not, the only lines where there is a std::cout to output something is in ConnexionTCP and the read function.

Comment: @NorthernLight Well something is wrong, print the length you're receiving, if you send "hi" that length should be 2, if it's more you're sending garbage from your client. To be extra sure you can `memset` your array with zeros before your `async_read` and see if you still have weird characters printed.

Comment: @sehe Yeah i agree, your solution is better

Comment: @NorthernLight You'll have to debug that yourself, or post a selfcontained example that exhibits the problem so we can explain it :/ See http://sscce.org and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Tank you for your attention. I ever tried with memset, but the "²²²²½½½½½½½½" stayed. What do you think about memset + "\0" ? Or maybe a splitter would be better ? But won't that be to slow ?